# javascript: $(window).height is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript that I am using to resize my background image to fit my window.   There are some confusing things going on that I just don't get.

1. Firebug and I assume my page doesn't recognize my `resizeFrame` function unless I place it below the body block.  Why?
2. Why am I getting the error:  `$(window).height is not a function`?

Any suggestions or insights would be helpful.

```
<!-- This this placed in <head> block -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script> <!-- This placed below body block -->
  jQuery.event.add(window, "load", resizeFrame);
  jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);

  function resizeFrame() 
  {
      var h = $(window).height();
      var w = $(window).width();
      $('body').css('background-size', w + 'px ' + h + 'px' );
  }  
</script>
```

Comment: I would guess it's not recognised because it has the error. Fix that first.

Comment: Why are you directly using jQuery.event.add instead of `$(window).on('load', resizeFrame);`

Comment: How can `resizeFrame` be referenced before it is defined?

Comment: Getting another error`$(window).on is not a function` in `$(window).on('load', resizeFrame);`

Answer (score 3):

You have the answer. `window.height` is not a function.

You want to change `$(window).height()` to `window.screen.height` to get the value.

Same with width.

Comment: `height` is a jquery function, the native window doesn't have `height`, but `innerHeight`,  `outerHeight`

Comment: Ah, oops. Amended answer, it should be `window.screen.height`

Comment: but `$(window).height()` should work, so even if your answer fixes the problem it doesn't answer the question. I'll remove the -1 though :-)

Comment: I never downvoted, but I too would like to know why `$(window).height()` doesn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing that jQuery only adds those functions to elements which actually have the property.

Answer (score 1):

if you're developing under wordpress you should use jquery() instead of $().
In your code you've got

> jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);

and

> var h = $(window).height();

that's why you got a mistake